# Which scriptures deal with Hanuman's life before he joined up with Rama?

Tags: scripture, hanuman

There are lots of TV serials that have incidents like Hanuman fighting Siva, trying to swallow the sun and so forth.

Are there canonical scriptures that are centered around Hanuman?

Comment: Being a popular deity, lots of folktales had been added to his lore. People being uncomfortable with story of his birth in Valmiki Ramayan, has given multiple version of that only.

Answer (score 0):

Check parasara samhita, there you can have knowledge

Comment: Sir, how about ShriHanuman ank of gitapress and is it authentic? I want to know about it.

Comment: I have gone through that, thanx to gita press, i learned more. I think it's authentic.

Comment: Thank you sir. 